# Binding issues with label but not listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

So I have done binding before and I'm not sure what is wrong with my binding this time. Can someone please explain to me why I can't bind my labels to the appropriate properties? The listbox works perfectly and as expected but I don't know why the labels aren't working.

**XAML**

```
<Label Content="{Binding MetricName}" Height="25"></Label>
    <Label Content="{Binding MetricUnit}" Height="25"></Label>
    <ListBox x:Name="EconomicSelection" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" Margin="5,5,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="399" FontFamily="{DynamicResource FontFamily}" FontSize="11" ItemsSource="{Binding EconomicBenchmarks}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="P" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Percentile}" Grid.Column="0" Width="30"/>
                    <Label Content="Value: " Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

**C#**

```
private Metric economicMetric;

    public Metric EconomicMetric
    {
        get { return economicMetric; }
        set
        {
            if (value == economicMetric) return;
            economicMetric = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string metricName;

    public string MetricName
    {
        get { return metricName; }
        set
        {
            if (value == metricName) return;
            metricName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string metricUnit;

    public string MetricUnit
    {
        get { return metricUnit; }
        set
        {
            if (value == metricUnit) return;
            metricUnit = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<EconomicBenchmark> economicBenchmarks = new ObservableCollection<EconomicBenchmark>();

    public ObservableCollection<EconomicBenchmark> EconomicBenchmarks
    {
        get { return economicBenchmarks; }            
    }

    public EconomicMeasuresTable()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event EconomicMeasuresChangedEventHandler EconomicMeasuresChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (propertyName == "EconomicMetric")
        {
            metricName = economicMetric.EconomicName;
            metricUnit = economicMetric.Unit;
            economicBenchmarks.Clear();
            foreach (var economicBenchmark in economicMetric.EconomicBenchmarks)
            {
                economicBenchmarks.Add(economicBenchmark);
            }            
        }
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));           
    }

    private void SetButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (EconomicMeasuresChanged != null)
        {
            EconomicMeasuresChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}

public delegate void EconomicMeasuresChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

**List**

```
List<Metric> metrics = new List<Metric>();

        metrics.Add(new Metric { EconomicItem = "NVP", EconomicName = "Net Present Value", EconomicBenchmarks = GetEconomicBenchmarks(new[] { 10, 50, 90 }, new[] { 400, 550, 700 }), Unit = "$m" });
        metrics.Add(new Metric { EconomicItem = "ROI", EconomicName = "Return On Investment", EconomicBenchmarks = GetEconomicBenchmarks(new[] {10, 50, 90}, new[] {10, 20, 30}), Unit = "%" });
        metrics.Add(new Metric { EconomicItem = "STOIIP", EconomicName = "STOIIP", EconomicBenchmarks = GetEconomicBenchmarks(new[] {10, 50, 90}, new[] {500, 550, 600}), Unit = "MMbbl" });
```

Comment: Try to debug the binding and see exacly what happens, a good example on how to debug binding see [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html)

Comment: Another way that you could check the state of the binding is with [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). This allows you to visually scope through your UI and see what their properties are internally, by checking the binding of the `Label`'s you should be able to see if they have been set correctly.

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: Sorry yes I have just and been experiementing with it, but how does this help me with my Label problem? I'm confused, the listbox works perfectly it's just the labels

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in this code is maybe incomplete and a bit strange. First of all, i would never use OnPropertyChanged to set any value, but maybe thats only my opinion...

Anyway, in the code you have shown us,you set metricName and metricUnit in OnPropertyChanged if property is EconomicMetric. But you never set EconomicMetric anywhere so the binding properties would never be set. You need to have a better look at your code.

Comment: Well I was aware I wasn't binding to this, and that is really my question how do I bind to this, I have a solution which I have been told is old fashioned but it does work, but I would just like to know how to Bind to Economic Metric

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your code is Metric class contains the collection **EconomicBenchmarks**, then why don't you bind directly that collection with view like this,

```
<ListBox x:Name="EconomicSelection" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" Margin="5,5,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="399" FontSize="11" ItemsSource="{Binding EconomicMetric.EconomicBenchmarks}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="P" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Percentile}" Grid.Column="0" Width="30"/>
                        <Label Content="Value: " Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Also when I do that binding to the listbox itemsource all my items are blank now, any reason why?